# Handle ajax errors with struts2-jquery-plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, struts2

We have a web application using struts2 with struts2-jquery-plugin, we need to capture the 403 http errors to redirect to login page when ajax call is requested. We put this code:

```
$(function () {
    //setup ajax error handling
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function (x, status, error) {
            if (x.status == 403) {
                redirectToLogin();
            } else {
                manageAjaxError(status, error);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is ok for all ajax requests but it's not working for jquery requests from struts2-jquery-plugin (for example: a call from sj:submit button), the code above is not executed.

One solution found is set **onErrorTopics** on each tag, but in tabs is not working (perhaps is a bug).

It is possible to set a global handling error for requests from struts-jquery-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I think error.status is what are you looking for, but you can try console

```
$(function () {
    //setup ajax error handling
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function (x, status, error) {
            if (error.status == 403) {
                redirectToLogin();
        } else {
            manageAjaxError(status, error);
        },

        complete: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    })
});
```